# php-intl not in mods-available after installation

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to make an update to an old application running PHP5.6 on Ubuntu14.04.

One of the packages I'm installing requires ext-intl.

I've installed this successfully with:

> sudo apt-get install php5-intl

However, after restarting Apache, the modules does not appear in the mods-available directory, so I am unable to enable it with phpenmod / a2enmod.

Are there any steps I've missed?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to install it by specifying the version:

> sudo apt-get install php5.6-intl

and verify if is present in:

> /etc/php/5.6/mods-available

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php5.6-intl
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.6-intl'

Comment: try to add ondrej repo:

 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

 sudo apt update

Answer (score 0):

ucf is probably masking the file on you.  It's a royal pain.

Try this script to pull the problems out of apt, purge ucf, then get the config files back. Yes, it's disgusting to have to do this.

This is `reinstall-purge-ucf`:

```
#!/bin/bash
PACKAGE=$1
apt-get install --reinstall $PACKAGE | grep 'Not replacing deleted config file' | awk '{print $6}' | tr -d '[$]' | tr -d '[\r]' |  xargs -t -n 1 ucf -p 
apt-get install --reinstall $PACKAGE
```

Now do, for example:

```
# ./reinstall-purge-ucf php7.4-json
ucf -p /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/json.ini
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/19.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 191911 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../php7.4-json_7.4.30-1+deb11u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.4-json (7.4.30-1+deb11u1) over (7.4.30-1+deb11u1) ...
Setting up php7.4-json (7.4.30-1+deb11u1) ...
Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php7.4 (7.4.30-1+deb11u1) ...
Processing triggers for php7.4-fpm (7.4.30-1+deb11u1) ...
NOTICE: Not enabling PHP 7.4 FPM by default.
NOTICE: To enable PHP 7.4 FPM in Apache2 do:
NOTICE: a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
NOTICE: a2enconf php7.4-fpm
NOTICE: You are seeing this message because you have apache2 package installed.
Processing triggers for php7.4-cli (7.4.30-1+deb11u1) ...
Processing triggers for php7.4-phpdbg (7.4.30-1+deb11u1) ...
```